# Can't create App Service Plan\App Service in SouthEast Asia region

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

Fyi, up until last week we were still able to create resources on the said region. Most of our existing resources are also in SouthEast Asia. We have also deleted an existing P3V2 App Service Plan from the said region to try to maybe free a limitation we have reached....

Comment: it's working just fine here, I created a resource group and a web app (with app service plan) in SouthEastAsia region and it's all running now. Do you see any error?

Comment: or, is it happening for any specific resource?

Comment: This should not be the case. I suggest opening a support ticket with Microsoft.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late update...we sent a support ticket to Microsoft and was verified as a bug in the portal. They gave as a temporary URL which had the fix and permanently fixed the issue the next day.

Comment: @RexArquero thanks for the update. Could you post it as an answer to help others?